# Convert AndroidManifest.xml to Binary

Tags: android, android-manifest, apk

I have an AndroidManifest.xml, and I need to convert it to binary and place it by hand in the APK. After that, I can do a manual sign and align.

Longer explanation: I'm having trouble [again] with the familiar tools used in APK re-engineering, and I'm bulding the APK by hand with tools that don't crash.

Android includes `sdklib.jar`, but I'm having trouble calling it (and it might not perform 'just' the XML -> binary conversion).

How does one convert `AndroidManifest.xml` to binary?

Comment: This pretty much sounds like a nightmare, but have you tried checking in the bin folder in the project?

Comment: Mozoby - it is :) I don't know why I torture myself.....

Comment: Supposedly aapt does this, but you have to repackage the entire apk file, which means you have to have access to the uncompiled resources if they're referenced in the AndroidManifest.xml.  using apktool I've decompiled it and got aapt to see all the resources.  It tries to put everything together but in processing the AndroidManifest, it falls apart complaining that the datatypes are wrong.  This seems to be related to the api version (which affects what is expected within the manifest).  And that's where I'm stuck..

Comment: Did you figure this out noloader? I am stuck with the same issue. ApkTool does not always work.

Comment: @Elitecoder - no, I never did find a tool. Kristopher Micinski might have some suggestions. He does a lot more with Android than I do.

Comment: @jww The canonical tool for resource packing is aapt. Do you have any problems with repacking all resources with aapt after extracting them with apktool?

Answer (score 8):

You can try to run aapt manually like this:

```
$LIBS"aapt" package -f -m -F output_unsigned.apk --auto-add-overlay -S main/res -J Temp/gen -G Temp/android-aapt.pro -A Temp/assets -M Temp/AndroidManifest.xml -I $LIBS"android.jar"
```

In my case (under linux):

- $LIBS"aapt" is a path to aapt file
- output_unsigned.apk is where to save created APK
- android-aapt.pro is where to save configuration for proguard
- Temp/gen, Temp/assets are my Android project folders
- Temp/AndroidManifest.xml is desired manifest
- $LIBS"android.jar" is JAR library for requested Android API level

It may not work for you out-of-the-box, but I hope it helps you to start with it. Consult aapt help for more details.

Answer (score 3):

If you have not seen it yet, there is [android-apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/), which is quite helpful for these kinds of things.  I have successfully used them before in repacking APKs by hand after modifying their binaries.

You can also look for the `apkbuilder` tool which is in my `android-sdk-linux/tools/` directory.  (It is, however, deprecated.)

Comment: Hi Kristopher. Thanks. APKTOOL is broken for what I am doing (its the familiar tool I was referring to). Both But.all's version; ibotpeaches version; and Mutiltools by the other fellow. APKTOOL has died on my last 3 BlackBox tests. Its not very robust.

Comment: Hm, that's funny.  We use the following to pack up APKs:


    java -jar apktool.jar b -f #{@dir} #{unsigned};
    java -jar signapk.jar platform.x509.pem platform.pk8 unsigned.apk unaligned.apk;                                         
    zipalign 4 unaligned.apk to_name